# Hamburger Menu Opens But Wont Close

Tags: html, css, frontend, bootstrap-5

I have html for my website below. With the code below, I can open the hamburger menu, but it won't close. I've seen posts saying the issue is html structuring, but when I run this through a validator I get no errors. I also don't see anything that jumps out as being wrong with my use of bootstrap. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.11.5/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-Xe+8cL9oJa6tN/veChSP7q+mnSPaj5Bcu9mPX5F5xIGE0DVittaqT5lorf0EI7Vk" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-kjU+l4N0Yf4ZOJErLsIcvOU2qSb74wXpOhqTvwVx3OElZRweTnQ6d31fXEoRD1Jy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/86461d8b85.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='main.css') }}">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
  <header class="site-header">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-steel fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand me-4" href="/"></a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarToggle" aria-controls="navbarToggle" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarToggle">
          <div class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('home') }}">Home</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('description') }}">Docs</a>
            <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('terms') }}">Terms and Conditions</a>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('select_game') }}">example</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('redeem') }}">example</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('log') }}">example</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('feedback') }}">Contact Us</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('acc') }}">Account</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('logout') }}">Logout</a>
            {% else %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('login') }}">Login</a>
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('register') }}">Register</a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
          <!-- Navbar Right Side -->
          <div class="navbar-nav ms-auto">
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
              <a class="nav-item nav-link" href="{{ url_for('acc') }}">Balance: ${{ account_balance }}</a>
            {% endif %}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main class="container">
    {% with messages = get_flashed_messages(with_categories=true)  %}
      {% if messages %}
        {% for category, message in messages %}
          <div class="alert alert-{{ category }}">
            <p>{{ message }}</p>
          </div>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endwith %}
    {% block content %}{% endblock %}
  </main>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide a working example.

Comment: already answered the question

Answer (score 0):

I have discovered that the problem is the first script and the seconds script are the same despite the different links. When comment out the second one on line 6, the collapse worked.